# Convert Requirejs handlebars references to Webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to convert my rather large project from requirejs to webpack, and I'm running into problems when trying to convert the handlebars templates to be handled by the `handlebars-loader`. I've got files that follow this format:

```
define([
  'hbs!templates/myTemplate',
], function(myTemplate) {...});
```

This assumes `dist/templates/myTemplate.hbs` exists. My webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './dist/scripts/index.js',

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      loader: 'handlebars-loader',
      test: /\.hbs$/,
    }],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.hbs', '.js', '.json'],

    root: [
      'node_modules',
      'dist,
    ],
  },

  resolveLoader: {
    alias: { hbs: 'handlebars-loader' },
    root: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
  },

  output: { filename: 'bundle.js' },
};
```

However, when I do this and run `webpack --config webpack.config.js` I get this type of error on every reference of a template in the project

> ERROR in ./~/handlebars-loader!dist/templates/myTemplate.hbs
>   Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of null

Any help would be appreciated. Feel free to ask clarifying questions as I'm completely new to webpack.

Comment: Found any solution yet ?

Comment: I was running the handlebars file through the loader twice. Webpack runs it automatically through the loader when I prefix the import with `hbs!`, and then again when it matched the loader test `/\.hbs$/`. I needed to choose either one or the other technique, but not both.